# Google play games services not working during testing phase

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

I developed a game using unity engine for android platform.

I have used GPGS plugin from github

But i was unable to "sign in" into GPGS during testing phase(A popup comes up saying "connecting to GPGS" loads 2 times and vanish).but as soon as i published my game on google play store,GPGS starts working properly(now i am able to sign in to my account).

Where i was wrong during my testing phase?

I already add tester email on google play console

Comment: Were you testing on device? Many plugins do not work completely in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub).

Maybe you missed some essential steps.

> To add testing access to an account:
>
> 1. Open the **Testing** tab for your game in the Google Play Developer Console.
> 2. Click the **Add testers** button.
> 3. In the dialog that appears, enter the email addresses of the Google Accounts that you wish to add as testers (one email address per
>      line).
> 4. Click **Add** to save your preferences. The tester accounts you added should now be able to access your Google Play games services.

You can also see this [forum](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/66420-gpgs-error-8-internal-error-on-login/#entry344599) for reference.